# Bootstrap Collapse in the Foreach loop and ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax, laravel

I use Bootstrap Collapse in the Foreach loop. What I want to do here is to show the data that comes with ajax when the button is clicked in the collapse pop-up area.

```
@foreach($depo_verileri as $veri)
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <div class="depo_veri_item" style="width:90%;">
                <span class="depo_kod">
                <a class="depo_sec" style="color:white;" data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapseExample" role="button" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseExample">
                        <i class="material-icons">
                        keyboard_arrow_right
                    </i>
                    {{ $veri['kod'] }}
                    <input id="{{$veri['id']}}" type="hidden" name="depo_id" value="{{$veri['id']}}">
                </a>

                </span>
            </div>
        </div>
        @endforeach
```

When I look at consol, whichever I click, the incoming data is always 1.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('.depo_sec').click(function(){
            var depo_id = $('input[name="depo_id"]').val();

            console.log(depo_id);

            return false;
        });
    });
</script>
```

I couldn't find exactly where I'm doing the error. Thank you for your advice in advance.

Comment: Hi, could you add a screen capture of the desired output ?

Comment: Your collapse anchor tag targets an element with id=“collapseExample”. Where is that element?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this looks like a normal behaviour

**Reason why ?**

You're generating multiple hidden inputs with exactly same selector `name` attr

**Way to fix it**

```
$('.depo_sec').click(function(){

      var depo_id = $(this).children('input:hidden').eq(0).val();

      console.log(depo_id);

      return false;
});
```

Working [Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/gt2upaxy/2/)

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @Foued MOUSSI.

You're generating multiple hidden inputs with exactly same selector `name` attribute.

Instead, you should consider replacing `name="depo_id"` with `name="depo_id[]"`
And do the changes accordingly at your frontend and backend code.

I hope this will help.